# Identify duplicates between two table and delete the one with older created time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables T1 and T2. Not all the columns are same on both the tables but both tables have Name and Date columns.

I want to check for duplicates in T1 and T2 on name, but delete the entry from the table which has older date.

for ex:
T1:

```
Name Date
A1   2012-09-09
A2   2018-08-08
A3   2015-04-06
```

T2:

```
Name  Date
A1    2019-07-07
A2    2016-05-05
A4    2015-09-06
```

I want to delete A1 from Table1 and A2 from Table 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using two exists delete queries:

```
DELETE
FROM T1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 t2 WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name AND t2.Date > t1.Date);
```

and

```
DELETE
FROM T2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T1 t1 WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Date > t2.Date);
```